# Ansible | AWS | modify subnet attribute auto-assign public ip

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there any module or attribute which will help in enabling modify auto-assign public ip for public subnet in Ansible.
My ansible version is 2.3.1.0.

Comment: Don't think it's possible with ec2_vpc_subnet but you can fire awscli as shell command: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-subnet-attribute.html

Comment: Yes have use currently used cli for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/21336) last year to add 2 AWS modules : `boto3` and `boto3_wait`.

These 2 modules allow you to interact with AWS API using boto3.

For instance, you could enable public IP auto-assignment by calling [`modify_subnet_attribute`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_subnet_attribute) method on EC2 service :

```
- name: Enable auto-assign public ip
  boto3:
    service: ec2
    region: us-east-1
    operation: modify_subnet_attribute
    parameters:
      SubnetId: subnet-xxxxxxxx
      AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation:
        Value: True
```

Feel free to give the PR a thumbs-up if you like it! ;)

Comment: Thanks for that it worked just want to know one more this does boto3 also support Application Load Balancer is there any same example of how to use it with ansible.

Comment: Yes, you can manage ALBs with [ElasticLoadBalancingv2 client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html).